# how can i use alternative of "Flatbutton" here?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

how can i use alternative of "Flatbutton" here?
*code given below**

```
TextButton(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
          side: const BorderSide(
              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 45, 43, 43),
              width: 1,
              style: BorderStyle.solid)),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      onPressed: () => buttonPressed(buttonText),
      child: Text(
        buttonText,
        style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 30.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
            color: Colors.white),
      )),
```

Comment: You like to get flat button style ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your style, this will work

```dart
TextButton(
  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
    foregroundColor: Colors.black87,
    minimumSize: Size(88, 36),
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
        side: const BorderSide(
            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 45, 43, 43),
            width: 1,
            style: BorderStyle.solid)),
  ),
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Text("A"),
),
```

More about [restoring-the-original-button-visuals](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons#restoring-the-original-button-visuals)